# .htaccess 301 redirect without GET var

Tags: .htaccess, get, http-status-code-301

For a website I'm currently working on we're redirecting our old URL's permanently to new ones like this:
Redirect 301 /oldfile.php http://www.site.com/show/newurl

Now I come across this situation in which the old url has a get var like:
Redirect 301 /oldfile.php?var=name http://www.site.com/show/newurl

This will redirect the oldfile to the new url plus it adds the get var so it redirects to:
http://www.site.com/show/newurl?var=name

How would I set up this redirect without the get var?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mod_rewrite` can strip off the query string:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?oldfile.php$ http://www.site.com/show/newurl? [R=301,L]
```